# How to add custom buttons in table view cell when user swipes in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to expose custom buttons when user swipe a cell in table view `(like mail app in iOS 8)` without using any third party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your buttons to the cell.contentView. Then, put another view on top that hides them, and add it a panGestureRecognizer attached so you can move it to the left when panning. Since the bottoms are behind, they will reveal themselfs.

There is an incredibly well detailed example here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views